# Match an exact phrase in Solr

Tags: indexing, solr, exact-match

I have indexed data in solr. I have many phrases such as 'The Dark Knight' and 'The Dark Knight Rises'. When I query for 'The Dark Knight', I get both the results, I want match this query with only 'The Dark Knight' and not the 'The Dark Knight Rises', is it possible to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want exact matches you could use a String field in Solr. I suspect the field that you are searching on is a Text field.

Be aware that on String fields the search will only succeed if the values are identical (including case, punctuation, spaces).

You can use the [Analysis Screen](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/analysis-screen.html) to see how matches will be made for these two different kind of field types.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible as discussed by "Hector Correa". Following should be the way to update schema for exact search.

```
<field name="exact_field" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

I have used this case for dictionary implementation where exact word is searched. "string" field type is the solution.